# mysql importing error on mysql host

Tags: mysql

Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `usersinputs` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1050 - Table 'usersinputs' already exists
```

Comment: As the error says the table is already there & you cannot create it

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if people read the error message or they just post it on Stack Overflow without even looking at it.

Comment: okay i read but just a beginner so it was hard for me to solve..Anyway thanks for your comment tadman

Answer (score 2):

Your error says it all. There is already a table named as `userinputs` in your database. You need to create a table with a different name or if there is any datatype change or any other alteration to the table then you need to `ALTER` the table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a table which already exists try one with another name.
You can however `alter` or check if the table exists:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usersinputs` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the table `usersinputs` is already exists in your database.

If you really want to CREATE a new table with the different columns and data types you can DROP the existing table and CREATE the new table by [`` DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `usersinputs`; ``](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-table.html)

So your code will be:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `usersinputs`;
CREATE TABLE `usersinputs` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Or simply want to change any column name or data type use [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)